# What is the use of _time64_t in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, time.h

Can someone explain to me what is _time34_t ? How will I use it ? I don't know how this _time64_t works. Should I use it as:

`CTime::GetCurrentTime(_time34_t);`

Comment: [This Microsoft-specific `time` function reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/time-time32-time64?view=msvc-170) might be helpful.

Comment: Besides that, if you want to be portable, not only between platforms but also between compilers, don't use any non-standard symbol beginning with an underscore. C++ have specified a set of symbols beginning with underscores, that you can use (as they are part of the C++ language) but anything else (like `_time64` and `__time64_t`) should be avoided in your code.

Comment: There is no such method [signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/ctime-class?view=msvc-170#getcurrenttime).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I will read the link that you give @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `_time64_t` in ATL or MFC. There is `__time64_t` (two leading underscores). That, however, is part of the (Universal) [CRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/c-run-time-library-reference), and not part of ATL or MFC either.

`__time64_t` is defined in *corecrt.h* as follows:

```cpp
typedef __int64 __time64_t;
```

In other words: a 64-bit signed integer type. Values of this type are commonly interpreted to hold the number of seconds elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1970 (also known as UNIX time). It is returned e.g. by the [`_time64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/time-time32-time64) function.

For ATL/MFC projects you can use [`CTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/ctime-class) for time and timespan calculations, although you should consider using C++' [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) instead. It's just an all around better alternative, easier to use, more robust, and works well with timezones and calendars.